# How to set the dimension of my Video Player Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I'm new to Unity and am trying to set the size of a Video Player, but this task seems so dificult.
Basically I'm loading my video from file using this:

```
videoPlayer.url = path;
```

Where the path is a variable that has the path of the video I'm using.
When my video is loaded into the player, it takes all the screen and I can't find a way to set the player dimension to like 100x100.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please state what you tried before. According to the documentation https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Video.VideoPlayer.html video player has width and height properties. Did you tried that?

Comment: Yeah, I tried but they are for reading the width and height of the player

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to set the dimension using a second camera.
Put my videoplayer inside the cam and set its viewport rect to they way I needed.
I think there has to be an easier way but this worked!